# Dynamic Validation Ranges Break when opening '07 file in '16

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I have Excel file with quite few macros for validation. There is date column which needs to be inside the range of Start/End date.  To Achieve this there is macro runs when data pulled out to create dynamic list with valid date for each row.  This solution works fine in with Excel 07.

Recently we upgraded to 2016 and the file gives the error as "we found problem with some content, do you want to recover?" every time when files get opened. When I say yes, it recovers the file. All data is intact but the Data Validations created for date is gets broken. Instead of the Values, source shown as #NA.

All the Data validations done based on list from excel stays intact but not the ones created via VBA.

Here is the screen shot before saving the file,

[image]

Here is how it looks after excel repairs the file when re-opening.

[image]

I tried to look for possible solutions and haven't found discussion related this.  Can anyone has comments/possible solution as how to handle this.

I have atleast 10 different validations similarly, so finding way to keep the list in formuala would be best solution rather than re-create whole logic for every validations in file..Here is the code which generates the dates as asked,

```
Sub Calculate_EOP_validation(FirstRow, LastRow)
If Sheets("Planning file").Range("C" & FirstRow).Value = 0 Then
   Exit Sub
End If
oldVS = DateSerial(0, 1, 1)
oldVE = DateSerial(0, 1, 1)
vCol = Mid(Sheets("Planning file").Range("PartEOP").Address, 2, 2)

For row = FirstRow To LastRow
VehSOP = Sheets("Planning file").Range("P" & row).Value
VehEOP = Sheets("Planning file").Range("Q" & row).Value

If IsDate(VehSOP) And IsDate(VehEOP) Then
    If VehSOP = oldVS And VehEOP = oldVE Then
        ValidDatesList = OldVDL
    Else
        Valid_date = VehSOP
        ValidDatesList = DateSerial(Year(Valid_date), Month(Valid_date)  + 1, 1) - 1
        Do Until Valid_date > VehEOP
            Valid_date = DateSerial(Year(Valid_date), Month(Valid_date) + 2, 1) - 1
            If Valid_date <= VehEOP Then
                ValidDatesList = ValidDatesList & "," & Valid_date
            End If
        Loop
        OldVDL = ValidDatesList
    End If
    With Sheets("Planning file").Range(vCol & row).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=ValidDatesList
        .ErrorTitle = "Wrong date entered."
        .ErrorMessage = "Please use drop-down list to select proper date."
    End With
    oldVS = VehSOP
    oldVE = VehEOP
End If
```

Next
End Sub

Comment: It would help to post your VBA code.  Also, what happens if you re-run the code, to recreate the validations?

Comment: Do you have anything in a `Workbook_Open` event, or in an XLA, that uses an unqualified `Rows.Count`?

Comment: 1. Yes, Re-Running the code fixes the dropdown 2. And Yes, as temporary solution I have these macro re-running in Workbook_Open. So basically it gives the recovered massage then macro runs to restore the validation, but this I done only after having problem.  Before that, there is no code involved in work_book open.

Comment: I can post the code, but I am not sure how to format them when posting here....Copy/Paste seems almost unreadable.

Comment: Just to add one more finding, if I place dynamically generated values in one of sheet and assign it as reference in Formula Excel 2016 treats it good and nothing losses when re-open saved file.  Problem seems only when dynamic generated values directly placed in formulas using macro as shown in first image. ( I may use this as solution, but it adds so much overload on excel data for each row, so keeping them in Macro would be good)